# How to add "readonly" option in PHP?

Tags: php

I am using Wordpress plugin Web 2.0 and now have a problem.

Many mobile users have a problem, because when they click the input field, the mobile keyboard shows up and blocks the contents.

I want to add a "readonly" option to the input field. But, I have no idea how to add that option in this PHP code.

https://gutentagkorea.com/business-listings

Maybe you can see the problem in this link.

Thanks

```
<div class="w2dc-col-md-12">
<?php
if ($search_form->isCategories()) {
w2dc_tax_dropdowns_menu_init($search_form->getCategoriesDropdownsMenuParams(__('Select category', 'W2DC'), __('Please select category', 'W2DC'))); 
} else { ?>
<div class="w2dc-has-feedback">
<input readonly name="what_search" value="<?php echo esc_attr($search_form->getKeywordValue()); ?>" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e('Enter keywords', 'W2DC')?>" class="<?php if ($search_form->isKeywordsAJAX()): ?>w2dc-keywords-autocomplete<?php endif; ?> w2dc-form-control w2dc-main-search-field" autocomplete="off" />
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

```
    public function getCategoriesDropdownsMenuParams($placeholder_category, $placeholder_category_keywords) {
        $term_id = w2dc_getSearchTermID('category-w2dc', 'categories', w2dc_getValue($this->args, 'category'));
            
        $params = array(
                'readonly'=>'true',
                'tax' => W2DC_CATEGORIES_TAX,
                'field_name' => 'categories',
                'depth' => $this->args['categories_search_level'],
                'term_id' => $term_id,
                'count' => get_option('w2dc_show_category_count_in_search'),
                'uID' => null,
                'exact_terms' => $this->args['exact_categories'],
                'hide_empty' => get_option('w2dc_hide_empty_categories'),
                'placeholder' => $placeholder_category,
        );
        if ($this->isKeywords()) {
            $params['placeholder'] = $placeholder_category_keywords;
            $params['autocomplete_field'] = 'what_search';
            $params['autocomplete_field_value'] = $this->getKeywordValue();
            $params['autocomplete_ajax'] = $this->isKeywordsAJAX();
        }
        
        return $params;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php 
  echo form_input(array('name'=>'what_search','value'=><?php echo esc_attr($search_form->getKeywordValue()); ?>,'size'=>'6',
  'readonly'=>'true'));//Or 'readonly'=>'readonly'
?>
```

and so on...

Comment: Unfortunately, the code doesn't work. I think this line of code is working now

if ($search_form->isCategories()) {
w2dc_tax_dropdowns_menu_init($search_form->getCategoriesDropdownsMenuParams(__('Select category', 'W2DC'), __('Please select category', 'W2DC'))); 
}